# Data Exchange between C++ Application (Sci)Python

Tags: c++, python, qt, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am developing a c++/Qt software for scientific purposes. While the Eigen library provides me with many operations to analyse matrices, it is still painful/hard to design a gui for all possible concatenations of operations. Therefore I am also exchanging matrices with Matlab at runtime. Since Matlab is not opensource and hard to get for students at my university, I want to do the same with python, so I could use e.g. SciPy for analysis. Therefore my question: How can I exchange data (e.g. sparse matrices) with python, especially scipy at runtime?

Note that I might think about this the wrong/complicated way, so I am open to other solutions for my problem. I tried PythonQt to eventually run my whole application in python, but it did not work with Qt4.8 yet and it would still mean a lot of work to make other parts callable by python. We are now using QScript, which as expected does not provide any tool for data analysis.

Comment: Can you give an example or two of "exchanging matrices" ? Say cA cB ... are matrices on the C side (what format ?), sC sD ... on the scipy side, and you want cA cB -> some scipy func -> sD -> back to cD ?

Comment: @Denis Exactly. My c++ code will generate some matrices, e.g. std::vector<double>, Eigen dense and sparse matrices, which I want to analyse in SciPi, e.g. compute conditions numbers, and send some results back to c++.

Comment: Maybe it depends on which parts of Eigen library you're actually using, but what about using Sage (http://www.sagemath.org/) for the whole project?

Comment: @Masci Looks like an interesting package. However I am making heavy use of half-edge data structures and advanced opengl in my software, which, at a first glimps, seems not what Sage is made for.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a couple of more knowledgable places to ask:

1) ask the [cython mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/cython-users)
(do you know [cython](http://cython.org) at all ?
Passing normal dense Numpy arrays down to C, and filling them in C, is easy;
can you preallocate a big enough Numpy array for your job ?)

2) [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/dev/datasets/index.html#datasets-in-svmlight-libsvm-format)
loads sparse array data files → scipy.sparse arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the propositions. I will have a look. ( see my response above to rdchambers )

Answer (score 0):

Cython  (which seems to be an offshoot of Sage) is a popular way to glue Python and C/C++. In my limited experience with it, it's quite elegant and effective.

They have a nice [tutorial on working with Numpy arrays](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html) (which is almost certainly how you should represent the arrays in Python). Of course, Numpy/Scipy provide a lot of the same numerics as Matlab.

Comment: thanks for the propositions. At first sight, it seems like a way to call my c++ code from python, while I'd prefer to connect a python console with my c++ application at runtime. Still, I will look into Cython more indepth and see if I can find a solution.

Comment: "to connect a python console with my c++": why not use pipes, see [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).Popen, and numpy [fromfile](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) / tofile ? Or ask a new question on e.g. "python <-> C over pipes".